# Is it safe to clear column caches in Rails production application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Is it safe to run

```
Klass.reset_column_information
Klass.connection.schema_cache.clear!
```

in production while rails app is running ?

I want to do zero downtime deploy and have a feature start working after background migrations are finished running. The background migrations are creating new tables so they will finish quickly.

From what I gathered in my short research. If my Rails app server is restarted and the tables are not yet created, `Klass` (which of course inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`) will cache the fact that table is not existing yet, during eager loading procedure when booting Rails app in production.

As long as the table is not existing when part of my code using feature related to `Klass` is hit i wanted to check for the existence of table named `Klass.table_name` and try to reload its schema. In some time (minutes) the table will be created by background migration, one last reload of the schema later, I could be using my new feature.

I don't worry about performance implications because this feature is not used often and most likely it won't be triggered even once before migrations are finished running.

TLDR:

- deploy rails app
- restart web server
- start running background migrations
- feature inactive
- finish running background migrations
- feature active

That would be the procedure.

I know I can split it into two deploys. Add new tables in background while old code is running, then do the deploy of features which require those tables. But I wonder if I could have a working solution with one deploy. I would like to avoid doing two deploys for new features just to have zero-downtime deploys.

Comment: Doing zero time deploy when you have pending migration is quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `Capistrano`, it provides all of the features you're looking for.

- Deploy new code to a new directory (not live)
- Run pending migrations
- Run any other deployment tasks, such as asset compilation etc
- Repoint the "live" site to the new code using symlinks
- Restart the app server

Here is the project:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano

This is a good tutorial:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/373-zero-downtime-deployment

Comment: This solution can be used for zero time deploy if you don't have pending migrations. Necessity of migrating data can bring you unexpected troubles.

Comment: You should be testing the deployment itself in a non-live environment prior to going live though. Deploying with `cap deploy:migrations` will ensure your migrations are run for you during deployment.

Comment: you are right. If site will accessible during migrations it can bring inconsistency in the database.

Comment: I guess that depends on the migrations. Capistrano also provides the ability to put the site into 'maintenance mode' during deployment to avoid these issues.

Comment: Yes. But it won't be zero time deploy, though :)

Comment: With database schema updates or data migrations, zero-downtime deployments don't really exist. No matter how fast you do it, there will be a period where the app either needs to be unavailable or locked to data writes. Automating the process with something like Capistrano can certainly minimise the issue however.